# Is there a way to determine the poll count of a REST API for a particular user?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I need to trigger a notification if a REST API has been polled a specific number of times for a particular user and if another condition too has been fulfilled. I am using a ConcurrentHashMap with userId as the key and an AtomicInteger as the value.

```java
public class MyClass{
    private static final ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, AtomicInteger> quoteRequestCount = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();


    mymeth(){
        map.putIfAbsent(<id of user>, new AtomicInteger(0));
        map.get(<id of user>).getAndIncrement();

       **//a set of operations

       AtomicInteger hitCount = map.get(userId);
       if (hitCount == 5 && condition which depends on above set of operations)
       {
            //send notification
       }
    }
}
```

Does a concurrenthashmap seem to be the most ideal choice here?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you scale your service by running multiple instances of it, then this may not work, depending on what sort of session affinity you have set up.

Comment: Spring Boot already exposes metrics, if you add the username as a key/value to that you are able to filter/query per user in a certain timeframe. Don't build this into your code, as that will introduce issues (one already mentioned above).

Comment: Further to @tgdavies If you have a cluster of services you will need to use something like hazelcast or redis to count across the multiple services.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions. I am discarding the above approach and considering the idea of using spring boot metrics as @M. Deinum pointed out.